# Как сериализовать структуру данных в JSON на C#?

Tags: c#, json

Например, есть простой класс

```
class Point
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

Как перевести содержимое этого класса в эквивалентную запись в JSON? Поиск подсказывает про библиотеку [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/), есть ли решение на основе встроенных средств языка (в частности для Compact Framework)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотрите встроенный [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string AverageRating { get; set; }   
}

List<Student> students = new List<Student>();

JavaScriptSerializer serializer = JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = serializer.Serialize(students);
```

Answer (score 2):

Класс для сериализации:

```
[Serializable]
public class Data
{
    public string Value;
}
```

И операция над ним

```
DataContractJsonSerializer s = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Data));
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(filename)
{
    Data data = s.ReadObject(fs) as Data;
}
```